# Swift UITableView really slow

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift2

I have a simple model `E-Numbers` and it reads from a .csv file. I cache the data into a variable `eNummers` in my ViewController so I can do basic array operations, such as `eNummers[0]`, `eNummers[1]`.

I read from the array in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but when I scroll the `tableView` it is really really slow and laggy. How can I optimize this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("globalCell") as UITableViewCell!

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "globalCell")
        }

        if (self.eNummers?.getAllNummers().rows[indexPath.row] != nil) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.eNummers?.getAllNummers().rows[indexPath.row][0]
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.eNummers?.getAllNummers().rows[indexPath.row][1]

            switch (self.eNummers?.getAllNummers().rows[indexPath.row][2])! {
                case "GOOD":
                    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                break
                case "MODERATE":
                    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
                break
                case "BAD":
                    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
                break
                default:
                    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                break
            }

        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: What does `getAllNummers()` do?

Comment: `func getAllNummers() -> CSwiftV {
        let nummers = CSwiftV(String: self.contents as! String)
        
        return nummers
}`

Comment: Put the numbers into an array.

Comment: You should make the call to `getAllNummers` once and then just access the array directly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Also,  if you have registered your cell class or are using a storyboard then `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` can't return. Il - this would seem to be the case since you have used `as!` which will throw an exception if nil is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `getAllNummers()` is loading a CSV file and parsing it 4 times for every cell. This will be your big slow down. You should load and parse the file once and store the values in a property and then use the property to access the values you need

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very much! :)
To clarify: I added the parsing part to the init constructor of my model, then called a property in tableView.